# Ember: Custom JSONAPISerializer

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, ember.js

I am having trouble persisting data back to the API after I create a new record in the datastore.

```
// routes/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return this.store.findAll('user');
  },
  actions: {
    test(name){
      this.store.createRecord('user', {
        username: name,
        email: 'email@email.com',
        is_staff: false
      }).save();
    }
  }
});
```

The REST API is expecting this request:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "User",
        "id": null,
        "attributes": {
            "username": "bill",
            "email": "email@email.com",
            "is_staff": false
        }
    }
}
```

Ember-data is sending this:

```
{
    data: 
    {
        attributes: 
        {
            username: "bill", 
            email: "email@email.com", 
            is-staff: false
        }, 
    type: "users"
    }
}
```

Here is what I have for a custom serializer, but Ember is not seeing it. Am I doing this right?

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

  normalizeCreateRecordResponse(store, type, payload){
    return {
      data: {
        type: 'User',
        id: null,
        attributes: {
          username: payload.username,
          email: payload.email,
          is_staff: payload.is_staff
        }
      }
    }
  }

});
```

On a side note, to make sure that the API is working right, I can send the data via a jQuery.post():

```
// routes/application.js

    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model(){
        return this.store.findAll('user');
      },
      actions: {
        test(name){
          Ember.$.post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/', {
            username: name,
            email: 'email@email.com',
            is_staff: false
          });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying the `normalizeCreateRecordResponse` method, but that is for when you  are getting data from the server back from the create record POST call.

If you want to modify the data sent TO the server you need:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_customizing-serializers

to use the `serialize` method ( there are other serialize methods for more fine grained control .. but this one is pretty simple to try out for what you want )

This link explains it. If you can't figure that out from there, let me know.